# python web scraping United Airline - "You don't have permission to access"

Tags: python, web-scraping, request, user-agent, http-status-code-403

Hi I'm trying to create a simple program to scrape price from the United Airline. However, when I try to scrape from the html I get an "access denied".
Here's my code:

```
class Unitedbot:
def __init__(self, f, t, *date):
    self.f = f
    self.t = t
    self.date = date
    self.search(f, t, date)
def search(self, f, t, date):
    print("Loading...")
    UNITED = "https://www.united.com/ual/ko/KR/flight-search/book-a-flight/results/rev?f={f}&t={t}&d={date[0]}&r={date[1]}&px=1&taxng=1"
    user_agent = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = requests.get(UNITED, headers=user_agent)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    print(soup)
```

This is the result I get:

```
Loading...
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
You don't have permission to access "http://www.united.com/ual/ko/KR/flight-search/book-a-flight/results/rev?" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.2d973b17.1595495409.4b3bc6cd
</p></body>
</html>
```

As you can see I even inserted the user-agent to my request headers. I don't understand the problem. Oh, also the status_code is 403. I printed out just in case.

Comment: 403 means you've tried to access a link you don't have access to, hence the access denied. I pasted that link and got exactly the same thing.

Comment: Do you have any solution for this? Like getting a GET method permission or anything

Comment: There's no "solution" to gain access to somebody else's website if you don't have the right authentication, barring asking them. If this is a page that requires you to be loged in then you'll need to call whatever API allows to you log in and get an authentication token first.

Comment: Okay i tried logging in using “selenium” but it has some layers of security in it, like ‘not recognizing the device’. Plus even if i’m logged into my browser and soup it, i still don’t have the access to parse the html. Is it possible that they are just not allowing the scraping? If it is how is Tripadviser/skyscanner doing all these stuff?